# Laravel Socialite callback auth('customer')->user() is null

Tags: laravel, authentication, session, oauth-2.0, laravel-socialite

**Laravel 6**

There are 2 possible scenario:

1. Logged in user connect to Google account
2. Guest user connect to Google account *(will create a new user if not exists)*

Let's talk about the first scenario

In my **routes/web.php**, no middleware

```
Route::get('connect/{provider}', [ConnectController::class, 'connect'])
    ->name('connect');
Route::get('connect/{provider}/callback', [ConnectController::class, 'callback'])
    ->name('connect.callback');
```

In **ConnectController.php**

```
class ConnectController extends Controller
{
    public function connect(Request $request, $provider)
    {
        $scopes = config('services.google.scopes');

        // dump(auth('customer')->user()); <------- this 1 has value

        return Socialite::driver($provider)
            ->scopes($scopes)
            ->redirect();
    }

    public function callback(Request $request, $provider)
    {
        $oauthUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();

        $user = auth('customer')->user();
        debugbar()->log('callback user: ' . ($user->name ?? 'null'));

        // ...

        if (!auth('customer')->check()) {
            debugbar()->log('user not logged in, log in now: ' . $u->name);
            auth('customer')->login($u);
        }
        return redirect()->route('accounts');
    }
```

Then the debugbar output is

```
log callback user: null
```

Suppose the user is logged in, and try to connect with google, but when reached the callback, the user session gone. What am I missing?

*P/S: The default auth driver is `admin`, cannot be changed.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day of research, I found out that the session ID is different from before navigate out to Google, and in the callback request.

Just update **config/session.php**, and set to `lax` *(originally was `strict`)*

```
[
    // ...
    'same_site' => 'lax',
]
```